# Npm not installing after updating and getting TypeError

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, installation, npx

when I check the node version and npm version in my nodejs terminal everything appears to be working fine. When I try doing something in VS code and run the, "npm -v", I get all this stuff below. I tried opening the folder via powershell and running npm -v but get the same stuff.

Node version is showing: v16.17.0

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:110
class SocksProxyAgent extends agent_base_1.Agent {
                                           ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:110:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:174:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\remote.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:110
class SocksProxyAgent extends agent_base_1.Agent {
                                           ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:110:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:174:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\remote.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
```